# How to create manifest.json file in wwwroot/dist/ folder with using node.js+NPM

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I'm just working with one project that builds on node.js+NPM commands. Now I'm stuck with this error

> DirectoryNotFound with no one file found in wwwroot/dist/manifest.jason file.

I have follow commands in D:\Shalin\InfoEnvoy3\InfoEnvoy3.Web>npm install and other commands like

```
go to project location at....\InfoEnvoy3.Web\node_modules\webpack-cli\
run below 3 command to install webpack at project location.
npm install --save-dev webpack
npm install --save-dev webpack-cli
npm install --global webpack
then run all below commands one by one
--npm link webpack-cli
webpack --env.configuration DEBUG --display-error-details --watch
webpack --env.configuration RELEASE --display-error-details
webpack --env.configuration RELEASE --env.buildType ANALYZE --display-error-details --profile
webpack --env.configuration RELEASE --profile --json
```

but no success with this and dist folder still empty as screen:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu3YC.png)

see dist folder no one have file. how to resolve this error.